# Complexity of a hash tables with balanced trees in the buckets

Tags: time-complexity, hash, hash-tables

If I use a balanced tree instead of lists in a hash table implementation, and also after initializing my table I don't enlarge nor reduce the size of the table, what would be the worst case complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you take a table of size 1 (the smallest possible case), what is the complexity?
2. If you take a table of size 42, what is the complexity?
3. If you take a table of size 2013, what is the complexity?
4. If you take a table of size $n$, what is the complexity?

> It's always the complexity of the balanced tree. Times a constant, which doesn't change the big oh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question: what is the amortized (average) initialization time complexity of this structure ?